# I cannot get my Glassfish Server on Intellij to run

Tags: intellij-idea, glassfish

I just installed Glassfish 5.1, trying to build a server. I followed [the instructions on their website](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-restful-web-service.html) but when I hit "Run" I only get

```
Waiting for server connection to start artifact deployment...
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
D:\Server\glassfish5\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat stop-domain domain1
```

while the Glassfish Log is empty. Here is the idea.log

```
    2020-02-19 16:35:04,346 [1217571]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
    2020-02-19 16:35:04,350 [1217575]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile 
    2020-02-19 16:35:04,702 [1217927]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.1/lib/jps-launcher.jar;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-12/lib/tools.jar 
    2020-02-19 16:35:04,746 [1217971]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder". 
    2020-02-19 16:35:04,747 [1217972]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation 
    2020-02-19 16:35:04,747 [1217972]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details. 
    2020-02-19 16:35:05,416 [1218641]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
    2020-02-19 16:35:05,416 [1218641]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil (file:/C:/Program%20Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ%20IDEA%202019.1.1/lib/protobuf-java-3.5.1.jar) to field java.nio.Buffer.address 
    2020-02-19 16:35:05,416 [1218641]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.google.protobuf.UnsafeUtil 
    2020-02-19 16:35:05,416 [1218641]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
    2020-02-19 16:35:05,416 [1218641]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stderr]: WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release 
    2020-02-19 16:35:06,271 [1219496]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -     COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 1928 ms: 0 min 1sec
```

So it says, that it built without errors, when I terminate tho it says

```
Application Server was not connected before run configuration stop, reason: Unable to ping server at localhost:4848
```

Hopefully someone has an idea whats going on here.

Comment: Please try IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.3 release: http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html. See if using JDK 8 helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't help. I installed the latest version and redid the Project, stll nothing.

Comment: What's the command line used to start the server? Does it work outside of the IDE in `cmd.exe`? It would help if you report an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA and attach the IDE logs: Help | Compress Logs and Show in ... Try getting the thread dumps using `jstack` from the Glassfish server process. See if disabling antivirus/firewall helps.